# How do I Dynamically add a Table row into the a table at certain position?

Tags: asp.net

Below is a snippet of the table that I would like to add a row to. I would like to add a row in the middle at a certain position of this table. (Not at the end and not at the beginning). I would like to pinpoint a certain position in the table a insert a row at that position. Should I go with traversing the table looking for the row by id?

for example:

```
For Each row As TableRow in tblDates.Rows

//Code for  statement to grab the position of the Table Row by ID
  If Row.Id = (Name of ID)

// code to add row
```

or is it more like a matter of somehow traversing the ASP Elements. I usually deal with C# so this is a learning moment for me honestly. any thoughts would help me understand.

```
 <table id="tblDates" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text="Date" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDateFormat" runat="server" Text="(MM/DD/YYYY)" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNumOfDays" runat="server" Text="Number of Days to Complete Action"
                        Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSubmittedToESO" runat="server" Text="Date Site Plan Submitted to ESO for Approval: "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubmittedToESO" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPWO" runat="server" Text="PWO: "></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPWO" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: How is this vba related? Are you doing this from a web browser control? Or are you talking vbscript? O is it purely ASP? Please update your question and tags

Comment: My apologies, good catch. That’s a mistaken Tag. This is more VB.Net.

Comment: get the row count and if greater than 0 divide by 2, then loop through the table and when the middle is reached run your code.

Comment: @JobesK thanks! I’ll try that. Is there a way that I can specifically choose exactly where in the <TR>  To insert? Like the middle is awesome, but I’d like to have more control of exactly where I place it. I’m thinking that Row Count is a great way to go possibly for that as well

Comment: what do you mean choose where exactly in the tr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would NOT do this at the markup level. We have a database system, or at the very least a whole boatload of data table, data row and even more objects.

So, do NOT do this at the UI level, but at the data level.

Say, A simple grid like this:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" >
        <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ><ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>'  />
                </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <br />
    Add new row at what position: <asp:TextBox ID="txtRow" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    
    <asp:Button ID="cmdRowAdd" runat="server" Text="+Add row" 
        OnClick="cmdRowAdd_Click"
        />
```

Code to fill like this:

```
Dim rstData As New DataTable

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData()
        GridView1.DataSource = rstData
        GridView1.DataBind()
        ViewState("rstData") = rstData
    Else
        rstData = ViewState("rstData")
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadData()

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Dim strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

And now we have this:

[image]

So, now we have that text box and button - add a row, and at what position.

That code is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdRowAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' add new row to grid at location choosen by user:

    Dim NewRow As DataRow = rstData.NewRow
    NewRow("HotelName") = "Hotel Name"
    NewRow("City") = "City"
    NewRow("Active") = False

    rstData.Rows.InsertAt(NewRow, txtRow.Text)

    GridView1.DataSource = rstData
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

So, if I type in 0 (first row), and hit button, then I get this:

[image]

So, normally, we would go

```
rstData.Rows.Add(MyNewRow)
```

but, you can as per above, use this:

```
rstData.Rows.InsertAt(NewRow, 2)
```

So, its near always better to manipulate your data at the data level, and if you need or want to display such results, then re-bind the grid or whatever.

Comment: This is so informative! Thank you so much! I will come back to visit this as a reference a lot as a constant refresher. I got bullied on here a few times for just trying to learn. This is extremely helpful. I didn't know there such a super clean way to approach this. I can literally shed tears. Thank you